# How to pass dockerfile environment variables to node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, environment-variables

How to pass dockerfile environment variables to node.js file? I followed the docker documentation for passing ENV variables, none of the variables are being passed. Any insight to the issue?

---

dockerfile:

```
FROM 10.118.224.132:5000/node:8.6.0-wheezy

ENV PORT 6000
ENV iamIP2="10.118.225.199"
ENV iamPort 9999
ENV iamPort2=9997
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY . .  

ENV mongoDBurl=10.118.225.149:27017/globalIndex
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

---

server.js:

```
"use strict";   

const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const request = require('request');

const link1  = process.env.PROXY_IAM_URI;
const iamIP ="10.118.225.164"; console.log("iamIP: " + iamIP);
//const iamIP = /\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+/g.exec(link1)[0]; console.log("iamIP: "+iamIP);
//const iamPort = /\d{2,}$/g.exec(link1)[0]; console.log("iamPort "+ iamPort);
const iamPort =0; console.log("iamPort "+ iamPort);

var iamIP2 ; console.log("iamIP2 "+ iamIP2);
var iamPort2 ; console.log("iamPort2 "+ iamPort2);
```

---

console.log (response):

```
[stdout][20d97485] iamIP: 10.118.224.164
[stdout][20d97485] iamPort 0
[stdout][20d97485] iamIP2 undefined
[stdout][20d97485] iamPort2 undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get them in Node.js with `process.env`

```
process.env.iamIP2      // "10.118.225.199"
process.env.iamPort     // 9999
process.env.iamPort2    // 9997
process.env.mongoDBurl  // 10.118.225.149:27017/globalIndex
```